# Bluetooth connecting - null pointer exception in startActivityResult()

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect two phones by bluetooth by my application.
I'm using this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html , but I have to do something wrong, because it doesn't work.
I want to show "enabling Bluetooth dialog":

```
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
```

[...]

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Log.v("BC", "Your device don't have bt");
    }

    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
```

And there is an error:

> 10-11 20:03:48.640: E/AndroidRuntime(32041): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3652
>   10-11 20:03:48.640: E/AndroidRuntime(32041): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-11 20:03:48.640: E/AndroidRuntime(32041):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
>   10-11 20:03:48.640: E/AndroidRuntime(32041):    at pl.piotrek.panitball.BluetoothConnection.uruchamianie(BluetoothConnection.java:24)
>   10-11 20:03:48.640: E/AndroidRuntime(32041):    at pl.piotrek.panitball.MainClass.doDraw(MainClass.java:86)
>   10-11 20:03:48.640: E/AndroidRuntime(32041):    at pl.piotrek.panitball.ViewThread.run(ViewThread.java:32)
>   Blockquote

What's wrong?!

Comment: Are you trying this on emulator?

Comment: No, on my phone (bluetooth is disable)

Comment: Did it satisfy the conditon mBluetoothAdapter==null ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are calling `startActivityForResult` from:

> pl.piotrek.panitball.MainClass.doDraw(MainClass.java:86) 10-11 20:03:48.640: E/AndroidRuntime(32041): at pl.piotrek.panitball.ViewThread.run(ViewThread.java:32)

worker thread? Maybe try from GUI thread?

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to configure the permission

```
<manifest ... >
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  ...
</manifest>
```